# How would I calculate the sum of the values of a band around a specific pixel in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, population, reduceregion, radius

I'm trying to calculate the population within a certain radius around a specific pixel, but I don't know how to define the geometry of the region to reduce.

This is what I would imagine it might look like, where "clipped" is the overall region:

```
var radiusPop = clipped.reduceRegion({

reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),

geometry:

scale: 30,

maxPixels: 1e9

});
```

Essentially I'm trying to add a band to my image that contains the population within a certain radius around the pixel. I can't figure out how to define the geometry for each pixel.

Comment: My suggestion is that you convert the pixel to a featureCollection using image.reduceToVectors() and then apply a buffer around the new featureCollection using ee.Feature.buffer()

Comment: @sermomon thanks! Which reducer do you suggest using here? I'm envisioning just a sum of individual pixel values, but I'm not sure how to reduce. Would it be "null," then operating over the selected geometry?

Comment: If you want to obtain the mean of the pixels population you should use ee.Reducer.mean(). This tutorial Will clarify https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/extract-raster-values-for-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You can for instance use `reduceNeighborhood()` to calculate the sum around all the pixels in the image, controlling the "geometry of the region to reduce" with the `kernel`. Then you extract the value for a specific pixel with `reduceRegion()`.

```
var populationSum = clipped.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  kernel: ee.Kernel.circle(200, 'meters'), // Control 
  inputWeight: 'mask'
})

var populationAroundPoint = populationSum.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
  geometry: point, 
  scale: 100, 
}).getNumber('population_sum')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/329c5e5109cecae8dcb70ab44bf81609

Comment: Perfect, thanks, this is super helpful! I'm wondering one other thing - when I display the map, the data appear to show correctly. But when I zoom in or out, the color changes in certain places. Is this because of some scaling issue? Why would there be a different display depending on the zoom level? See here for an example: zoomed out (https://i.imgur.com/SsWJREG.png), zoomed in (https://i.imgur.com/OMPg2Hp.png). Is one of these inaccurate?